# Rails Precompile Assets Error on Local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, local

Trying to precompile assets on my my local machine. I keep getting the following error. How can I fix this?

-ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]
- Rails 5.0.0.1

```
rake assets:precompile production --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'production' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:71:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:151:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: are you trying to precompile the assets in `production` environment ?, try this `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace` if not, just `rake assets:precompile --trace` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `RAILS_ENV` with the command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

This way rails will precompile the assets using the production environment settings